# When do you need to write `any` when using a protocol as a type in Swift 5.7

Tags: swift, existential-type

I found that this piece of code generates no errors

```
protocol Foo{
    func foo()
}

let x: Foo? = nil
```

While the following starts complaining `Use of protocol 'Foo' as a type must be written 'any Foo'`

```
protocol Foo: ObservableObject{
    func foo()
}

let x: Foo? = nil      //Use of protocol 'Foo' as a type must be written 'any Foo'
```

Since `ObservableObject` inherits `AnyObject` so I tried

```
protocol Foo: AnyObject{
    func foo()
}

let x: Foo? = nil
```

Which again gives no errors.

What exactly is the condition in which writing `any` when using protocol as type is necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the proposal that introduced `any` - [SE-0335](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0335-existential-any.md#source-compatibility),

> [SE-0309 Unlock existentials](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0309-unlock-existential-types-for-all-protocols.md) for all protocols enables more code to be written using existential types. To minimize the amount of new code written that will become invalid in Swift 6, I propose requiring any immediately for protocols with `Self` and associated type requirements. This introduces an inconsistency for protocols under the Swift 5 language mode, but this inconsistency already exists today (because you cannot use certain protocols as existential types at all)

So it is required for writing existential types of "protocols with `Self` and associated type requirements" since Swift 5.6. `ObservableObject` is such a protocol, with an [`ObjectWillChangePublisher`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject/objectwillchangepublisher) associated type.

Note that in Swift 6 and above, or in the Swift 6 language mode, existential types of all protocols need `any`.